# Calculate average time

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I calculate average time in Crystal Reports given a collection of different times?

`Average Time` refers to the average start time when a given doctor starts diagnosing patients. I only have 1 `SELECT FROM WHERE` statement and cannot `INSERT` data into any database table, so I'm unclear how to calculate this value.

I tried using a separate SQL Command for just this calculation, but the results weren't on the same conditions (WHERE statement conditions and current doctor name for each row). I also tried this [formula](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/message/9361825) but don’t know how to adapt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **Running Total**.

If you group by doctor, all the individual times will show up as records in the details section. (Or you can configure this in a subreport if necessary.)

Then create a Running Total that summarizes the time value (no dates included), evaluates for each record, and resets on change of group (doctor). Place this in the Doctor's group footer.

Again, you can set this up in a subreport too if your main report can't be configured with this grouping.